# XPath query to validate an element before another

Tags: xml, xpath

Using XPath into SonarQube I fall into an issue that I'm not able to find a query to validate if an element is before another element.

For example, in the next XML I'm trying to check if the element `<BIN_PACKAGE>` has a preceding `<BIN_SCHEMA>` element.
If it has, it should just ignore the statement and if it doesn't, it should have the `<BIN_SCHEMA>` select the `element/elements` node.

```
<COMPILATION_UNIT tokenValue="CREATE" tokenLine="1" tokenColumn="0">
    <PL_SQL_COMPILATION_UNIT_NO_EOF tokenValue="CREATE" tokenLine="1" tokenColumn="0">
        <CREATE_PACKAGE tokenValue="CREATE" tokenLine="1" tokenColumn="0">
            <CREATE tokenValue="CREATE" tokenLine="1" tokenColumn="0"/>
            <OR tokenValue="OR" tokenLine="1" tokenColumn="7"/>
            <IDENTIFIER tokenValue="REPLACE" tokenLine="1" tokenColumn="10"/>
            <IDENTIFIER tokenValue="PACKAGE" tokenLine="1" tokenColumn="18"/>
            <BIN_SCHEMA tokenValue="NEXUS_GIS" tokenLine="1" tokenColumn="26">
                <BIN_IDENTIFIER tokenValue="NEXUS_GIS" tokenLine="1" tokenColumn="26">
                    <IDENTIFIER tokenValue="NEXUS_GIS" tokenLine="1" tokenColumn="26"/>
                </BIN_IDENTIFIER>
            </BIN_SCHEMA>
            <DOT tokenValue="." tokenLine="1" tokenColumn="35"/>
            <BIN_PACKAGE tokenValue="PKG_EM_GI" tokenLine="1" tokenColumn="36">
                <BIN_IDENTIFIER tokenValue="PKG_EM_GI" tokenLine="1" tokenColumn="36">
                    <IDENTIFIER tokenValue="PKG_EM_GI" tokenLine="1" tokenColumn="36"/>
                </BIN_IDENTIFIER>
            </BIN_PACKAGE>

            ...............

        </CREATE_PACKAGE>
    </PL_SQL_COMPILATION_UNIT_NO_EOF>
</COMPILATION_UNIT>
```

I get this XML format from sslr pl/sql toolkit

Comment: did you tried `//BIN_SCHEMA/following-sibling::BIN_PACKAGE`

Comment: @Andersson Just test ti and is not what i'm looking for.  Like i said i want to get the BIN_PACKAGE that are missing the previous element BIN_SCHEMA.

Comment: @zx485 I was talking about 1 or more elements

Comment: @zx485 Running SonarQube to test it but almost sure it does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An XPath to select all `<BIN_PACKAGE>` which have no preceding `<BIN_SCHEMA>` elements
relative to the `/COMPILATION_UNIT/PL_SQL_COMPILATION_UNIT_NO_EOF/CREATE_PACKAGE` axis is:

```
BIN_PACKAGE[count(preceding-sibling::BIN_SCHEMA) = 0]/BIN_IDENTIFIER/IDENTIFIER
```

In this expression `/BIN_IDENTIFIER/IDENTIFIER` represents your desired target expression `element/elements`. Replace it as you like.